# Ruby errors during installation with devkit and native gem building

Tags: ruby, rubygems, msys2

I have errors when installing ruby on windows and afterwards some native gem builds fail.

I installed Ruby+Devkit 3.2.2-1 (x64) from https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

The expected behavior is that it should install correctly however when installing the msys base installation there is all kinds of errors related to keys:

```
gpg: error retrieving 'alexey.pawlow@gmail.com' via WKD: No data
gpg: error reading key: No data
gpg: refreshing 1 key from hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key F40D263ECA25678A: "Alexey Pavlov (Alexpux) <alexey.pawlow@gmail.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
... Repeats for other keys ...
```

But the `Install MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain ...` shows:

```
Install MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain succeeded
```

If I try to run the `idk install` command again:

It shows msys is ok:

```
MSYS2 seems to be properly installed
```

but `Install MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain ...` the following error:

```
> pacman ... lots of packages here ...
error: failed to init transaction (unable to lock database)
error: could not lock database: Permission denied
Install MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain failed
Installation failed: pacman failed
```

- This is happening on a Windows 11 machine.
- I also tried 3.1.4-1-x64 and2.7.8-1-x64  with the same result
- I removed the existing msys installation from the path.
- Pure ruby gems can be installed.
- Some native ruby gems build and install.
- Other native gems do not build.

Answer (score 0):

I had to start an command shell as administrator.

Execute `ridk.cmd install` and select option `2 - MSYS2 system update (optional)`

Now it was able to update the keys and more native build ruby gems can be installed. Some still fail.